# Looking for a keyboard shortcut to minimize the current window of an app, without minimizing all of them

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I often have multiple Intellij windows open and I find the need to minimize a single window without hiding the other Intellij windows.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>M</kbd>  should minimise the current frontmost window [assuming Intellij follows proper Mac Toolbox rules.]

I'm sure this used to be user-adjustable, many OS versions ago, but I can no longer find it referenced anywhere in Prefs.

Double-click works too, and is still a pref - idk if it's still in Ventura, can't test.

[image]

<sup>Photoshop used to offset the floating drop menu.</sup>